# Insert dynamic date field in mail merge

Tags: date, ms-word, mailmerge

This seems like a basic question but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I want to insert a "date" field into my mail merged letter at the top. I can't find any field for date in Word 2007. I want this field to update automatically according to the current date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. On the Ribbon, click the **Insert** tab.
2. Click **Date and Time** (part of the **Text** group).
3. From the Date and Time dialog box, select the date format desired.
4. Click the **Update automatically** check box.
5. Click **OK**.

[image]